# Opaque Token Implementation in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, token

im trying to create a secured spring rest api for the security i want to use opaque token stored in the database so that if the client query on the api with a bearer token . the server will check on the database if the token exist if the token is valid and get the user and the privilege and check if the user have the authority to do the request. i've done some research on the net but didn't found result that can be understood by a beginner. how can i implement this.
[method 1 found](https://alainelkhoury.hashnode.dev/spring-security-oauth-20-opaque-token-authentication) [method 2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/opaque-token.html) i have found this two methods but i dont know where too implements the database verification and validation

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... Are you really trying to implement a Spring based OAuth2 authorization/resource server or do you just want to secure your endpoints using opaque tokens? In the latter case, these tutorials only help to a limited extent. They describe an OAuth2 workflow. If you're an absolute beginner with Spring Security, I recommend to start with simpler authentication mechanisms than OAuth2, HTTP Basic for example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer yes i am trying to secure my endpoint using opaque tokens i've found this method by using sanctum auth on laravel. the access token will be a randomly generated string. they dont really explain how to implement it and i didn't found any tutorial that use this kind of token.

Comment: If you are a beginner i suggest you start out by implementing form login that uses session based authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research i've found this and it is working
first i've created a Authorization filter like this :

```
package com.example.bda_test_11.security;

import com.example.bda_test_11.model.BdaUser;
import com.example.bda_test_11.model.Token;
import com.example.bda_test_11.repository.TokenRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j
public class AuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    public AuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        super(authenticationManager);
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String tokenCode = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        log.info(tokenCode);
        if(tokenCode == null ) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        Token token = tokenRepository.findByCode(tokenCode).orElse(null);
        if (token == null) {
            
            filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
            return;
        }
        BdaUser user = token.getUser();
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getLogin(),null,user.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userToken);
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

and a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter like this

```
package com.example.bda_test_11.security;

import com.example.bda_test_11.security.domain.LoginCredentials;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
@Slf4j
public class JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();



    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        try{


            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
            LoginCredentials authRequest = objectMapper.readValue(stringBuilder.toString(),LoginCredentials.class);
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    authRequest.getLogin(),
                    authRequest.getPassword()
            );
            setDetails(request,token);
            log.info(token.toString());
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
        } catch (IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

if the connection is successful we generate a token like :

```
package com.example.bda_test_11.security;

import com.example.bda_test_11.model.BdaUser;
import com.example.bda_test_11.model.Token;
import com.example.bda_test_11.repository.TokenRepository;
import com.example.bda_test_11.service.BdaUserService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Slf4j @Component
public class AuthSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    private final BdaUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public AuthSuccessHandler(TokenRepository tokenRepository, BdaUserService userService) {
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        UserDetails principal = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        BdaUser user = userService.findByLogin(principal.getUsername());
        Token token = new Token(user);
        tokenRepository.save(token);
        log.info(token.getCode());
        response.addHeader("Authorization",token.getCode());
        response.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        response.getWriter().write("{\"token\":"+token.getCode()+",\"login\":"+user.getLogin());
    }
}
```

and then ive configured the filterChain bean like this

```
package com.example.bda_test_11.security;

import com.example.bda_test_11.repository.TokenRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;

@Configuration
public class BdaSecurity {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Autowired
    public BdaSecurity(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler, TokenRepository tokenRepository) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.authSuccessHandler = authSuccessHandler;
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth)->{

                    try {
                        auth
                                .antMatchers("/api/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                                .antMatchers("/api/user").hasAuthority("USER")
                                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                                .and()
                                .sessionManagement()
                                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                                .and()
                                .addFilter(authenticationFilter())
                                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager,tokenRepository))
                                .exceptionHandling()
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
    @Bean
    public JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
        JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter filter = new JsonObjectAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(authSuccessHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }
}
```